# Display xml element by it's attribute with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement, xpath

This is my first xsl program, so it must be a dummy question. However I tried all combinations that I could see in "if" condition. But it didn't work and I can't figure out. There must be a synthax error with my XPath expression. I want to display only "n=1" elements. My code is like:

my.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="my.xsl"?>
<lorem>
<ipsum n="1">
    <id>1</id>
    <type>asd</type>
    <cost>800</cost>
</ipsum>
<ipsum n="0">
    <id>2</id>
    <type>asd</type>
    <cost>1000</cost>
</ipsum>
</lorem>
```

my.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<!--some code-->

<xsl:for-each select="ipsum">

 <xsl:if test="@n=1"><!--wrong part-->
  <xsl:sort select="cost" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
  <tr>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="type"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="cost"/></td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>
```

my script for display

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
}
else 
{
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult(){
xml=loadXMLDoc("my.xml");
xsl=loadXMLDoc("my.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
    ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=ex;
}
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
    xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
    resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
    document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(resultDocument);
}
}
```

I'm glad of any help and suggestion.

Comment: Try starting with `<xsl:for-each select="ipsum[@n=1]">`. The rest should be obvious, I think. Note that there is an assumption here that you are already in the context of `<lorem>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your XSLT in so far as the `xsl:sort` must be the *first* thing inside the `for-each`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ipsum">
 <xsl:sort select="cost" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>    
 <xsl:if test="@n=1"><!--wrong part-->
```

but as user3016153 suggests in a comment, you should consider putting the test as a predicate on the `select` and then you wouldn't need an `if` at all:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ipsum[@n = 1]">
 <xsl:sort select="cost" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
```

Your current approach is "process all the ipsum elements, and for each one if it is n=1 then ... otherwise do nothing", the predicate approach is "process the ipsum elements that have n=1, and for each of them ...".